# Get the image visible area state to set the image in canvas at previous dragged location

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

### **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aab7j/2/)**

I have JQuery script that allows me to drag the images inside Canvas. PLease see the attached JSFiddle reference.

My Question is, Let's say I have dragged the image to left, Can I get the current state of the image how much portion we can see? So that next time when I load the image in Canvas, it should first show that portion which was visible last time

```
var drag, canvas, ctx;
var posX = 0, posY = 0;
var lastX, lastY;
$(document).ready(function(){
    canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var image=document.createElement("img");
    image.onload=function(){
        canvas.width = 600;
        canvas.height = 200;
        ctx.drawImage(image,posX,posY);
        init();
    }

    image.src="http://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/poster_rodents_big.jpg";

    function init(){
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
            drag = true;
            lastX=null;
            lastY=null;
        });

        document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
            drag = false;
        });

        document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
            if(drag){
                var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
                var x = mousePos.x;
                var y = mousePos.y;
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                if(lastX && lastY){
                    posX += x-lastX;
                    posY += y-lastY;
                    if(posX>0) posX=0;
                    if(posY>0) posY=0;
                    if(posX<-image.width+canvas.width) posX = -image.width+canvas.width;
                    if(posY<-image.height+canvas.height) posY = -image.height+canvas.height;
                    ctx.drawImage(image,posX,posY);
                }
                lastX=x;
                lastY=y;
            }
        }, false);
    }

    function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
            y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it will be what you need but why don't you store the posX and posY in a cookie or localStorage every time the image move. And then retrieve the stored position when page load. Something like that :

```
//Store the position :
localStorage.setItem('position', JSON.stringify({x:posX,y:posY}));

//Top of your script
var lastKnown = localStorage.getItem('position');
if(lastKnown) {
  var parsed = JSON.parse(lastKnown);
  var posX = parsed.x, posY = parsed.y;
} else {
  var posX = 0, posY = 0;
}
```

You can find a modified Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Aab7j/5/)

Comment: can u tell what is localStorage ?

Comment: LocalStorage is kind of an enhance version of the cookies but has the following advantages/evolutions : 1/a lot of storage space that 2/persists beyond a page refresh and 3/isn’t transmitted to the server. You will have a complete reference here http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html. Just be sure that your browser requirements match the support of localStorage.